# What are the consequences of LHC results for supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider

Forgive me my ignorance, I'm just an undergrad. That said, I have listened a couple of talks and lectures in the last years - given by experts in the field - about the future of fundamental theoretical research in physics, mainly concerning our best bets for a theory of everything, in particular string theory. For exemple, the five messenger lectures by Nima Arkani-Hamed where he talks why space-time is doomed others cutting edge topics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZWGBYDBoGw&t=4s).

In the talks, always supersymmetry is mentioned, for instance how it is the best candidate of a theory of everything and the last(?) consistent hope for string theory, and more, that in this decade we would be able to reach the collision energy necessary and predicted within the theory to detect supersymmetry. Ultil now, from what I've been reading in last years, no good news for supersymmetry have been stated. Could someone experienced or with some familiarity in the subjec explain to me how is the case for supersymmetry in the present time? And what consequences to string theory - as a theory of everything - the no discovery of supersymmetry in the LHC will bring?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44264/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54733/2451  and links therein.

Comment: I think your question is effectively duplicated in the links provided by Qmechanic. In case you don't don't get an answer,  (my apologies if you know this already), two people who have written seperate  skeptical reviews of String Theory are Lee Smolin and Peter Woit, both of whom think there are more problems than just the ones you have mentioned. There are lots of  books that are written by people who do believe it is a valid field. Luckily for me, I don't know enough to even try to judge.