# What are the implications if Supersting theory is discredited?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider

Please forgive my ignorance, I am not a student of physics in any capacity, therefor my understanding of string theory is extremely limited to say the least. Based on the recent lack of evidence in support of SUSY at the LHC, my question is: what are the implications if Superstring theory is debunked? (again, please forgive my ignorance) What will this mean for the theory of a multi-dimensional universe? Does this theory have any basis in regards to the Holographic principle theory and evidence in support of it (quantum entanglement, implied digital storage of information and planck length etc)?  What about recent discoveries put forth by Prof.James Gates in regards to mathematical equations suggestive of computer codes found within SUSY equations?  As I said I am a novice, so please, the simpler the answers the better. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54733/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This seems related too, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15/2751, and Lubos answer still holds.