# No supersymmetric particles have been found in the LHC. Isn't this proof that Supersymmetry doesn't exist?

Tags: supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider

The LHC can reach energies from $7(TeV)$ to $13(TeV)$ (see [here](https://home.cern/science/engineering/restarting-lhc-why-13-tev)) and the question of which this is supposed a duplicate. Which I think it isn't, because in that question (which has been asked already eight years ago) there is nothing asked (which obviously just couldn't) about the current situation. In an answer to it, it is said that until 2020 (which is just a guess) the lower bound of SUSY particles will be reached. Now the lightest sparticle is the [neutralino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralino) with a supposed mass of about $300(GeV).$, which is 40(!) times as high as the energy the LHC can supposedly reach and I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that there are sparticles which have a mass lower than this. I couldn't find the mass though of the next lightest sparticle (after the neutralino) predicted by any theory that incorporates SUSY. For sure, the neutralino hasn't been found though. Maybe that's because it's difficult to find them, Which I don't know. Wouldn't (in the light of this) the next sparticle (with respect to mass) have been found yet?

So isn't this proof that the search for supersymmetric particles is a search in the dark for nothing and supersymmetry is non-existing?

Comment: Generally,absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, not being limited to physics.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54733/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the question marked as duplicate! Can we please learn how to vote for re-opening in such cases? This is an important question, a hot issue in particle physics, the currently offered answer doesn't cover it - and since it is closed we cannot give other, proper, answers.

Comment: @Qmechanic why do you say that these are the same question? Imho the only common thing among them is the word "Susy".

Comment: I totally agree with you, @Helen!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is *not* proof. There are supersymmetric models in which supersymmetry would not be detectable at LHC energies. For an example, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0405159).

Do not confuse the general idea of supersymmetry with a particular supersymmetric model such as MSSM, the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model, which does now seem to be untenable.

Comment: Why is the MSSM ruled out? And what is the mass of the lightest sparticle (after the neutralino) predicted by a generic physical theory in which supersymmetry is used? I couldn't find this on the net.